# How do I tell which libraries were statically linked by GCC

Tags: c, linker

I have a C program that I hope to run on bare-metal (in a SystemC model). Which means I can't rely on an OS or any shared libraries existing.

I've taken care of the file input/output routines and manually wrote them to work on bare-metal. I've also compiled using static linking:

```
gcc -static my_app.c -o my_app
```

However, when I run the program, it seems to infinite loop as it enters the `.iplt` section. I suspect that it's attempting to jump to a function table that I haven't correctly loaded into memory (since an OS isn't there to manage this).

My question is: after compiling a program, how do I tell what was successfully statically linked (and is part of the binary itself) and what external libraries the program relies on the OS for? Is there a report the linker creates that I can inspect?

Comment: I suspect you're producing an ELF executable (i.e. because `.iplt` is an ELF-like thing). Try doing: `file my_app` to identify what it is. Some libs don't have static versions. You can also try: `ldd my_app`. Also, `readelf` and/or `objdump`. Maybe you should post your `my_app.c` so we can see what [functions] it's trying to use.

Comment: I don't know too much about `systemC` but, from wikipedia, it appears to be for generating H/W logic (a simpler replacement for `verilog` or `VHDL`)??? This isn't quite "bare-metal", which, to me, that's just code that runs after a CPU reset from ROM (e.g.) a BIOS, bootloader, or other standalone program that runs on a CPU arch (e.g. `arm`).

Comment: If you're compiling for bare metal using GCC, then you should probably be specifying the `-ffreestanding` option, which is specifically for telling GCC to build an executable that does not rely on support from a host operating system.  That should also prevent you from relying on most of the standard library, which indeed is a necessity for such a program.

Comment: @CraigEstey SystemC is a hardware simulator language. We have a CPU (ARM A55) created in such an environment and are trying to run benchmarks (Spec2000 in this case) on it. SPEC is written to run on an OS. I'm trying to figure out how to make it bare-metal. My initial attempt seemed to have failed...

Comment: Okay ... I have some _small_ experience with writing device drivers [and linux porting] for future H/W under gate level and functional simulators. And, some experience cross porting to/from (linux/RTEMS or VxWorks/RTEMS or VxWorks/linux). So, what OS does SPEC2000 normally run on? Where is the SPEC source? What are the API calls it needs? I would assume a limited number of the full libc. Why bare-metal? If `systemC` is S/W emulated gate level, I would understand, but what are _your_ reasons?

Comment: Bringing up an OS on our model would take way too long. And we don't have fileio in our current model (might bring that in in the future). SPEC2000 can run on any OS (it's main target is Linux but I've run it on MacOS and Windows). The source code requires purchasing (which I've done) so I cannot share it. One of the benchmarks is basically GCC compiling a file. I've already stubbed the fileio to read/write to memory (fmemopen) instead of file. Now I need to figure out what else I need to stub/reimplement to make bare-metal.

Comment: By "too long", do you mean programmer time to port it? Or, the simulation time? There are lightweight libc impl that are designed for embedded. RTEMS is free, impl a lot of linux API, designed to run on limited embedded (originally developed to run on spacecraft). Or, `ucLinux`, is linux for embedded (runs _without_ MMU--do you have one?). Or, `FreeRTOS` is easy to port. All these already have ports to arm and one should be close [enough] to your platform for a starting point. Otherwise, you're going to be spending a lot of time recreating libc APIs.

Comment: And, are you incrementally stubbing things, and then testing on systemC [gate level]? I'd do the S/W under `qemu-arm` first [_functional_ simulation]. Then, when it is running (no missing APIs, etc.), only then would I put it on systemC. That's a lot less work [and it was how I did it in the past after trying to do it directly on a gate level simulator]. You've not listed the API calls you have to port [as I already asked about].

Comment: You want to run the SPEC benchmark for `gcc`? I just got a count of the number of libc/libm calls `gcc` wants: 153 undefined symbols. Try: `readelf -s /usr/bin/gcc | grep UND` to get a list. And, `gcc` is _just_ the front end for the various compiler stages that it will invoke. So, if you have to stub/impl 153 functions, by the time you're done, a lightweight RTEMS port will seem like nothing.

Comment: You'll likely want to compile with `-ffreestanding` regardless, because this tells the compiler not to sneak library calls into the machine code which wasn't there in the source.

Comment: I see. I'm using FILE* to feed to fmemopen which requires the stdio.h. -ffreestanding would choke on that. Is a baremetal replacement library available somewhere for common C library functions? With some defined by me of course (malloc, free, stdin, stdout).

Comment: I mean simulation time. To simulate 176.gcc in SPEC2000, it'd take *weeks*.